# Match a word for pattern and extracting the whole word

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a function that would match a part of a single word with an entered text and print the entire word if that pattern is present in that word . I am using c++.Please help.
Below is a function that i tried writing using string functions but with this i can only find out if a word is present in a sentence or not. But i need to extract that single word whose part matches an entered text. I hope my question is clear.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool contains_word(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& word)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    // Find the start of 'word' in 'sentence'.
    while ((pos = sentence.substr(pos).find(word)) != std::string::npos) {
            if (!(isalpha(sentence[pos - 1])) || !(isalpha(sentence[pos + word.size() +1])))
                    return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question: you want to extract the matched word... but if your matched word is `word`, then, what is the problem ? Why not simply `bool contains_word(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& word) { return sentence.find(word) != std::string::npos; }` ?

Comment: no . i dont want to match the whole word. i want to match a part of a word like .. if the entered text is "terminal" then the function would try to match it to the ubuntu application name "gnome-terminal" and like wise .If "terminal" is present in the name then it would extract the whole name that is "gnome-terminal".

Comment: Ok, and is `sentence` a real sentence ? In other words: do you have mutiple separators, or only spaces ?

Comment: i am sorry for the variable name but sentence is not an actual sentence,it is a string variable containing a single word taken from a file which contains all the ubuntu gui-based application names.

Comment: Ok, but, there is a separator between these names, no ?

Comment: yes ..there are spaces in the file between the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string get_word(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& substr)
{
  std::string::size_type it = sentence.find(substr);
  if(it == std::string::npos)
    return "";

  std::string::size_type it2 = it;
  for(; it >= 1 && !std::isspace(sentence[it - 1]); --it);
  for(; it2 <= sentence.size() - 1 && !std::isspace(sentence[it2 + 1]); ++it2);

  return sentence.substr(it, (it2 + 1) - it);
}

int main()
{
  std::string str("kchmviewer gnome-terminal");
  std::cout << get_word(str, "viewer") << std::endl;
  std::cout << get_word(str, "terminal") <<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

```
kchmviewer 
gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Thanks . It works as I want it to. I'll try if a single word is present in the string without any space. Thanks again.

Comment: I've just edited my post, there was a little bug when the word was at the beginning and end of the text.

Comment: this program returns a blank when a substring is not present . i want to discard that not matched string instead of returning a blank.

Comment: never mind .used a global variable to store the matched word and had to return an integer to show there was a match .if there was then use that global variable containing the matched word.

Comment: Yeah ,or instead of use a global variable, you could pass a `std::string&` as third parameter, and return a `bool`.